# Вызов события при изменении стандартного свойства WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, property

Нужно в UserControl обработать изменение значения высоты контрола. То есть что бы вызывалось событие при изменения HeightProperty. Делаю так:

```
    public new double Height
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(HeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeightProperty, value); }
    }
    public new static readonly DependencyProperty HeightProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Height), typeof(double), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(500.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(HeightChangedCallback)));

    private static void HeightChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("its ok");
    }
```

И вроде бы работает, но в итоге это свойство теряет возможность выставения Auto высоты. Как такое правильно реализовать, когда нужно обработать стандартное свойство?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нужно в UserControl обработать изменение значения высоты контрола.

Надо подключить обработчик к событию SizeChanged.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" />
```

---

```
partial class MainWindow : Window {
  public MainWindow() {
     InitializeComponent();
     dg.SizeChanged += (s, e) => { 
        if (e.HeightChanged) 
           Console.WriteLine("its ok"); 
     };
  }
}
```